# flutter local notification: what's the channel id?

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I'm using [flutter_local_notifications](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_local_notifications#-readme-tab-), and to create a notfication (let's focus on android ) you do the following:

```
var androidPlatformChannelSpecifics =
        new AndroidNotificationDetails(
          'your other channel id',
          'your other channel name', 
          'your other channel description');
    var iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics =
        new IOSNotificationDetails();
    NotificationDetails platformChannelSpecifics = new NotificationDetails(
        androidPlatformChannelSpecifics, iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics);
```

As you can see in the android case you provide 3 parameters related to a channel
So my quesiton is what this channel is used for and why in android we need to provide an `id`, a `name` and a `description` to it ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

notification channels give us the ability to group notifications and let user interact with those channels.

Let's assume you are building a chat application, you can group messages coming from *Alice* under channel *channel-alice*, and you can only mute *channel-alice* or do different actions to it.
Channels are required after API level 26.

Comment: so I can use the same channel in my whole app for all the notifications ? or I can use multiple channels and each channel contains some notifications ?

Comment: Definitely, you can put all notifications in one channel or you can separate notifications into channels by their context.